# Remove call stack from Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

Security officers asked to remove(or clear) call stack inside of azure application insights for security reason. We already discussed the possibility to export only "allowed" information to some storage account, and block app insights for everyone, but it will block a lot of other useful features of monitor.
I've spend a few hours googling, but haven't found anything applicable for me

Comment: What is in the call stack that is compromising the security?

Comment: You might be able to do it through TelemetryInitializer - check if it is Exception and then clear call stack.

Comment: But, yes, usually call stacks are not considered sensitive information. For it to be considered one it means that people who have access to telemetry must not have access to the source code (otherwise they can get these call stacks from there). And overall, the source code must be considered secret.

Comment: well, i don't know the reason they want to remove it. some security policy, cause they are healthcare organization. we are very limited in our access to azure portal, and, they want to reduce our access more. But, question is the question. Thanks for telemetry, i'll investigate it

Answer (score 0):

To trace the Call Stacks in Azure Application Insights, Microsoft has released a NuGet Package known as `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCallstacks`.

This package extends the Application Insights SDK for .NET to generate Call Stack information for every dependency collected.

To stop getting this Call Stack data, remove the package from your project. After you remove the package, all new requests will be displayed in the default UI on the Azure Portal.

Please check this [Azure Article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/dependency-call-stack-and-application-insights-sdk-labs/)  for more information.